# Cutecom installation fails on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, qt, makefile, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install cutecom on OSX Mavericks but I'm getting some erros.
Here are the steps that I followed.

1. install qt through brew

   brew install qt
2. update path on .bashprofile

   export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/bin:$PATH
3. extract files of cutecom
4. compile source code of cutecom

   $ mkdir build

   $ cd build

   $ cmake ..

   $ make

And the output of make is:

```
[ 20%] Generating ui_cutecommdlg.h 

/Users/kc/Downloads/cutecom-0.22.0/cutecommdlg.ui: Warning: The form file has external pixmaps or qPixmapFromMimeSource() set as a pixmap function. This requires Qt 3 support, which is disabled. The resulting code will not compile.

[ 40%] Generating moc_qcppdialogimpl.cxx Scanning dependencies of target cutecom

[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cutecom.dir/main.cpp.o

In file included from /Users/kc/Downloads/cutecom-0.22.0/main.cpp:21: 

In file included from /Users/kc/Downloads/cutecom-0.22.0/qcppdialogimpl.h:22:

/Users/kc/Downloads/cutecom-0.22.0/build/ui_cutecommdlg.h:12:10: fatal error:     
          'Qt3Support/Q3MimeSourceFactory' file not found
    #include <Qt3Support/Q3MimeSourceFactory>
             ^  
1 error generated.   

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cutecom.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1  

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cutecom.dir/all] Error 2   

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Kostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Qt package you have is missing Qt3Support ([on purpose](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10360)). This component is necessarily for some Qt4 software that still uses deprecated features dating back to Qt3.

[Based on the documentation I've been able to find online](http://wiki.icub.org/wiki/Homebrew#QT4), you should be able to reinstall Qt4 with the extras you need using a command like this:

```
brew install --with-qt3support qt
```